# Chunked encoding, streams and content-length

Tags: node.js, stream, chunked-encoding, content-length, node-request

I need to upload a gzipped file. For performance in case my string gets too big I decided to use streams but ran into an issue with the server requiring a *content-length* header which cannot be calculated as the gzipping is inline. I then decided to use chunked transfer but am not sure if I am either not doing this correctly or if the server will simply not accepting streams/chunks as it still returns an error about needing a *content-length* header.

Here's the bit of the code:

```
const gzip = zlib.createGzip()
let stream = createStream(string) // I also use files hence the streaming
  .pipe(gzip) )
  .pipe(request.put(url, {
    headers: {
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'blockblob'
    }
}))
```

Response:

```
Content-Length HTTP header is missing
```

I've also played around with adding other headers such as:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
```

Is my only option to just forgo streaming or gzip out of the flow and calculate length that way?  I can't tell if I am missing something or of the server is being persnickety.

Comment: Sounds like the server doesn't accept or understand chunked encoding, since the use of such implies that `content-length` is unnecessary, and vice versa.